# Canvas animation react

Tags: reactjs, animation, canvas

I want to create an animated canvas in ReactJs. I have a functional component. I created a class named circle with two methods: draw and update. When I instance circle, I want to call draw, but i have this error from the browser:
TypeError: cir.draw is not a function

I tried with const draw = function() {...} but is the same.

If you know a better way to crate an animated canvas I'm opened for suggestions. In Js it is easiest for me, but React has some difficulties for do that, I think.

This is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  var canvas;
  var c;
  var radius = 40;

  var circle = function (x, y, dx, dy) {
    const draw = () => {
      c.beginPath();
      c.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      c.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
      c.stroke();
    };

    const update = () => {
      if (x + radius > window.innerWidth || x - radius < 0) dx = -dx;
      if (y + radius > window.innerHeight || y - radius < 0) dy = -dy;
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
    };
  };

  var Animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
    var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
    var dx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 15;
    var dy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 50;

    let cir = new circle(x, y, dx, dy, c);
    cir.draw();
    console.log(cir);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("a");
    Animate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This tutorial will help you:
http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2019/08/19/animating-a-canvas-with-react-hooks/

Comment: Thanks! I will see that!